# C++ How do I get the element at index i and check if it is empty in a vector or array

Tags: c++

Is there any way I can find if the element at index `i` is empty or not like a `.isEmpty()` function in C++ in a vector and array

1) Get element `i` in array or vector

and

2) Check if it is empty

For integers

Comment: It depends on what the array or vector contains. There is no "empty" value for int, floats, doubles, etc.

Comment: first check with vector size, if `i > size` its outside range. otherwise get element at index i and check `vector[i] == null`

Comment: There is no such concept as "empty array element" or "empty integer" in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors and arrays in C++ are always full up to their size.  Every element up to their size exists.

If the element itself has an empty state, then `buff[i]` accesses the element; ask it like you'd ask any other instance of that type.

Integers do not have an empty state in C++.

You can make a type "nullable" with `std::optional`; so `std::vector<std::optional<int>>` is a vector of possibly missing integers.  This is [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), but boost implemented `optional` in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

For an optional, you can `static_cast<bool>` it to see if it is emoty, then use `*` to access it if it is not.